# Web socket connection request handled by get route in Spark framework

Tags: websocket, jetty, spark-java

I have the following mappings:

```
webSocket("/test/",Tester.class);
get("/home",Controller.getHome,templateEngine);
get("/:param/",Controller.getRoot,templateEngine);
```

I get the following error when connecting to the websocket at test

```
Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200
```

as the request gets handled by the get /:param route map. However, the get request to /home is not handled by /:param, and is handled by /home as expected. How can I enforce that the route map to work correctly for web sockets too?

Comment: The route `/:param/` should never alter the response in the case of a `connection: upgrade` (aka websocket).  Does yours?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that. But, I have verified that the route handler for the get /:param/ handles the web socket connection for some reason.

Comment: the problem is that `:param` will match any string, including "test". That's probably why it handles the websocket request to `/test`

Comment: By digging a little bit in Spark code for another issue, I saw that Jetty requires to have the websocket handler added as the last one of the handlers. So probably the matching GET handler is handling the request before the websocket handler.